# Web Scraping pagination using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, pagination

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
root_url = "https://hjrs.hec.gov.pk/index.php?r=site%2Franking&page=1"
html = requests.get(root_url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

paging = soup.find("div",{"class":"grid-view"}).find("ul",{"class":"pagination"}).find_all("a")
start_page = paging[1].text
last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text

outfile = csv.writer(open('Mona.csv', 'w', newline=''))
outfile .writerow(['Title','Links'])

pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
for page in pages:
    url = 'https://hjrs.hec.gov.pk/index.php?r=site%2Franking&page=1' %(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    #print(soup.prettify())
    print ('Processing page: %s' %(page))

    Title_list = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive w-100 d-md-table"})
    for element in Title_list:
        Title1 =Title_list.find_all('a')
        Title = Title1.contents[0] 
        Links ='https://web.archive.org8' + artist_name.get('href')

        writer.writerow([Title,Links])

outfile.close()
print ('Done')
```

It gives me this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-f28d946aff93> in <module>()
     12 outfile .writerow(['Title','Links'])
     13 
---> 14 pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
     15 for page in pages:
     16     url = 'https://hjrs.hec.gov.pk/index.php?r=site%2Franking&page=1' %(page)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '»'
```

kinldy explain how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`last_page` gets `»`, which can't be parsed as `int`. You can get the right page number as such:

```
last_page = paging[-1]['data-page'] + 1
```